# How do I prevent Resident Evil (HD remaster PC version) from crashing when saving?

Tags: technical-issues, resident-evil-2002

The HD remastered remake version of *Resident Evil* (PC) is crashing when I try to save. See the crash log below:

[image: crash log image]

> Fatal error.
> Failed open file. C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Resident Evil Biohazard HD
> REMASTER\nativePC\mnlts\serviceinfo 5

Also, I've noticed that this just happens when you play with Chris using the *RE5 Costume*.

Comment: Can you provide information about your PC's system specs?

Comment: @Stevoisiak thank you, but I already found out the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it by turning off the *Auto Data Upload* setting:

[image: Auto Data Upload Configuration]